# Is bash > redirection atomic?

Tags: bash, cron, atomic, io-redirection

I've weird problem with my crontab job. My crontab job does the following:

```
program > file
```

Sometimes however file gets filled with random data that I can't explain.

I wonder if it could be the previous crontab job that's taking longer to run and it somehow mixes its results in `file` with current crontab job?

Overall my question is: is `>` operation atomic? Meaning if two programs do `> file`, then the last one to finish will have its data in `file`?

Comment: If you want to simply avoid two instances of your program running at once, you can use `GNU Parallel`, but invoke it as `sem --id mySemaphore program` to make a mutex type semaphore.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Do you mean I should just run my cron job through parallel?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-mutex-and-counting-semaphore

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not atomic. Not even a little bit atomic.

The redirection does two things:

1. It opens the file *by name*, creating it if necessary.
2. It truncates the file.

After that, the utility is started, with its `stdin` assigned to the opened file.

If two scripts do that more or less at the same time, they will both end up writing the same file, but since they will have independent file descriptors, each process will overwrite the other process's output, resulting in a grand interleaving of bytes, some from one process and some from the other.

Another common race condition relates to the fact that the file is truncated (by the shell) before the utility starts executing. Consequently, even if the utility only writes a single line to the file, it is possible that a concurrent utility which reads the file will find that it is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what will happen in the end if two processes write to the same file at the same time, overwriting each others output? Would I get garbage data that I described? Or would it contain the output of the last process that finishes writing to the process?

Comment: @bodacydo: Normally, you'll get garbage. Each process writes at its own write position, and the two processes are asynchronous with respect to each other, so you'll get some bytes from one and some bytes from the other. You can even get gaps if you're unlucky.

Answer (score 3):

It's not atomic. You can verify it easily yourself:

```
( { echo a ; sleep 3; echo b ; } > 1) &
( { echo c ; sleep 1 ; echo d ; } > 1 )&

sleep 5 ; cat 1
```

Answer (score 2):

bash `>` is done with an `open` with the flags (for bash 4.3.30 at least) `O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` (from line 707 of make_cmd.c)

So each will truncate the file, and write to it.  If a previous process still had an open file handle it would continue writing, and at its seek position into the file, being unaware that another process had truncated the file.